# Problems switching scenes (transitioning from one to another)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder, scene

I'm writting a GUI with 2 scenes, the first one being one to connect to the server (which has been written already and works great), and the second one, the game itself.

I've looked up tutorials, but I haven't seen one so far that could also load the FXML. I've tried doing it on my own, but I was unsuccessful. I've implemented 2 separate controllers, and 2 separate FXML's, but I'm not managing to implement all of the above in the Main.java, and cannot switch scenes either with a button, my code looks like this at the moment.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application {
Stage window;
Scene scene1, scene2;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    window = primaryStage;

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("GUI v3.0");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 700));
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/sample/R_enormousRing.png"));
    primaryStage.show();

    //Stage 2
    //secondaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 700));
    Parent secondary = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));


    String hostName = "localhost"; // hard coded at the moment, but I'm trying to get the values from the "login" scene and use those 
    int portNumber = 2123; //idem
    Socket serverSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
```

**Controller.java**

```
public class Controller {


@FXML
private GridPane grid;

public void initialize() {
// useless code for now
}
```

**Controller2.java**

```
public class Controller2 {

//empty for now 



}
```

and I hope that the FXML's aren't necessary right now.

**Updated code**

```
public class Main extends Application {
@FXML
public Button button;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SceneOneController.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    primaryStage.setTitle("GUI v3.0");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 700));
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/sample/R_enormousRing.png"));
    primaryStage.show();

    //Stage 2
    //secondaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 700));

    button.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
        FXMLLoader innerLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainController.fxml"));
        try
        {
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            Parent innerRoot = innerLoader.load();
            stage.setTitle("Scene One");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(innerRoot, 700, 700));
            stage.show();
            primaryStage.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
```

and errors

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:945)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:35)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

Comment: You can look at what I did [here](https://github.com/sedj601/SplashScreenTest/blob/master/Main.java) with a splash screen practice app.    app root ->https://github.com/sedj601/SplashScreenTest

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, looks pretty much what I needed. I'm trying to replace your `task.setOnSucceeded` with a `setOnMouseClicked`. I have created a button in the first scene and gave it an id "btn", so that in the end it looks something like `btn.setOnMouseClicked((Event event) -> {` but it still gives me an error saying that the symbol is not found, althought it has been initialized in the Scene one controller but it still won't work, what to do?

Comment: Post your updated code.

Comment: Just a guess, but If you are loading data, you probably want to do the button handler in the` setOnSucceeded`. That way when the data finish loading your button can now be used to take you to the next scene.

Comment: Refresh the thread if you could, it's right at the buttom, I've locked up the syntax of it, and it looks ok but?

Comment: make sure you have imported `JavaFX` controls and not `awt`.

Comment: you were right, the controls were at fault, but now there are even more errors 

I've updated the code and errors, could you have a look at it again please? Your help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: `button` will not be initialized in the instance of `Main` created when you launch the application. It will only be initialized in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sample app, I add a `Button`. I set the `Button` to `disabled`. I load the `Splash Screen`. When the `Splash Screen` finish loading, I `enable` the `Button`. If the `Button` is clicked, it loads the first `Scene`.

> Main

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication104 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        FXMLDocumentController mainController = loader.getController();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();

        Button button = mainController.getButton();
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            FXMLLoader innerLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SceneOne.fxml"));
            try {

                Stage stage = new Stage();
                Parent innerRoot = innerLoader.load();
                stage.setTitle("Scene One");
                stage.setScene(new Scene(innerRoot, 500, 500));
                stage.show();
                primaryStage.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        button.setDisable(true);

        final Task task = new Task<Void>()
        {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
                    updateProgress(i, 100000000);
                }

                return null;
            }
        };

        task.setOnSucceeded((Event event) -> {
            button.setDisable(false);
        });

        mainController.getPBSplashValue().progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        mainController.getPISplash().progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

        new Thread(task).start();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

> 1st Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    ProgressBar pbSplash;
    @FXML
    ProgressIndicator piSplash;

    @FXML
    Button button;

    public ProgressBar getPBSplashValue()
    {
        return pbSplash;
    }

    public ProgressIndicator getPISplash()
    {
        return piSplash;
    }

    public Button getButton()
    {
        return button;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {

    }
}
```

> 1st FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication104.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0">
         <children>
              <VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity">
                  <children>
                      <ProgressBar fx:id="pbSplash" prefWidth="200.0" progress="0.0" />
                      <ProgressIndicator fx:id="piSplash" progress="0.0" />
                  </children>
              </VBox>
            <Button fx:id="button" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
    </children>
</StackPane>
```

> 2nd Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class SceneOneController implements Initializable
{

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

> 2nd FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication104.SceneOneController">

</AnchorPane>
```